# How to sort an array of components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a nested map to iterate through my data and then return a react component for each object I have in my Data. Check the code below:

```
return props.dataArray.map((classObj) => {
                    return classObj.timetable.map((timetableObj) => {
                        if (timetableObj.weekday === props.day) {
                            return ttCard({
                                lecturer: classObj.lecturer,
                                module: classObj.module,
                                room: classObj.room,
                                class_id: classObj.id,
                                timetable_id: timetableObj.id,
                                startTime: timetableObj.start_time,
                                endTime: timetableObj.end_time,
                                weekday: timetableObj.weekday
                            });
                        }
                        return null;
                    });
                });
```

My issue is that my component aren't sorted and they have to be sorted because it is a timetable for students. Look at the image below and notice how 10:30 AM is the latest card in my tab view:

[image]

**things I tried so far:**

1- creating a new array then sorting it after the `if statement` block - not working
2- returning a sorted array to a function and mapping that array to return the component - not working
3- looping and returning the object as a function within the component parameter:

```
ttCard( sortedArr.forEach((ttObject) => {
return ttObject
}))
```

also not working

I have googled and tried to research but no hope so far. I know that initially my nested map is bad but this is how my object looks like:

```
[
    {
        "class_code": "English-5-G-2-L-1911-test-teacher",
        "id": 23,
        "lecturer": "test teacher",
        "module": "English-5",
        "room": "L",
        "timetable": [
            {
                "end_time": "9:00",
                "id": 37,
                "start_time": "8:00",
                "weekday": "Sunday"
            },
            {
                "end_time": "10:00",
                "id": 38,
                "start_time": "9:00",
                "weekday": "Sunday"
            },
            {
                "end_time": "10:00",
                "id": 47,
                "start_time": "9:00",
                "weekday": "Monday"
            },
            {
                "end_time": "10:00",
                "id": 48,
                "start_time": "9:00",
                "weekday": "Tuesday"
            },
            {
                "end_time": "11:30",
                "id": 52,
                "start_time": "10:30",
                "weekday": "Tuesday"
            },
            {
                "end_time": "11:30",
                "id": 54,
                "start_time": "10:30",
                "weekday": "Thursday"
            },
            {
                "end_time": "12:30",
                "id": 58,
                "start_time": "11:30",
                "weekday": "Thursday"
            },
            {
                "end_time": "14:00",
                "id": 61,
                "start_time": "13:00",
                "weekday": "Wednesday"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you sort them in the parent component instead, seeing as they are props? If not, would you consider sorting them in the constrcutor and storing the sorted results in `this.state`? Because sorting them EVERY RENDER seems awfully bad for performance to me

Comment: Sort & Map will work as expected,.. Problem is your not showing this code, so it's hard to suggest were you went wrong.  Also when sorting your times, think about 0 padding the times, as `9:00` is after `11:20` in string sort.. but `09:00` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort` on your output to arrange the array by startTime

```js
.sort((a, b) => {
    // These lines are so we can directly compare the times
    // I would recommend to send timestamps down with your data (if possible)
    var aTime = a.startTime.replace(':', '');
    var bTime = b.startTime.replace(':', '');

    // Sort by smallest first
    return aTime - bTime;
  });
```

I would also suggest filtering out null values in your array

Using your example -

```
var classesArr = props.dataArray.map((classObj) => {
  return classObj.timetable.map((timetableObj) => {
    if (timetableObj.weekday === props.day) {
      return {
        lecturer: classObj.lecturer,
        module: classObj.module,
        room: classObj.room,
        class_id: classObj.id,
        timetable_id: timetableObj.id,
        startTime: timetableObj.start_time,
        endTime: timetableObj.end_time,
        weekday: timetableObj.weekday
      }
    }
    return null;
  }).filter(x => x); // Filter out any null values
}).filter(x => x); // Filter out any null values.

// Flatten array so it is sortable/mapable
return [].concat.apply([], classesArr).sort((a, b) => {
  // These lines are so we can directly compare the times
  // I would recommend to send timestamps down with your data (if possible)
  var aTime = a.startTime.replace(':', '');
  var bTime = b.startTime.replace(':', '');
  // Sort by smallest time first
  return aTime - bTime;
}).map((x) => {
  return ttCard(x);
})
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your answer but it is not working, i parsed it into an int but still. Any other solutions?

Comment: @ZyzzShembesh My bad, I have updated the sort now to use `return aTime - bTime;` Tested with your array and it works :)

Comment: Hey, thank you again for your help, I tried it again and it is still not working :(. did you see how my data looks like above?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "not working"? Here is a JSFiddle showing the sort working https://jsfiddle.net/phmq230r/

Comment: basically my list comes out the same. 10:30 is still the last card. sorry for late reply but i had issues with my ISP. this Js fiddle contains my whole data list. can you try and display classes in timetable that are on a Sunday only and sorted? 

https://jsfiddle.net/oymz8h4w/

Comment: @ZyzzShembesh Okay, I see your issue now. Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/eqrwfmjh/5/ I have moved the sort to sort after the filtering. I also added some extra filtering to remove the null values from the map. If this works for you, I will update my answer

Comment: ok we are going places lets go! now I am facing a weird issue... not all the data is actually displaying. For example, on Sunday only 4 classes are displaying but I actually have 6 classes in my data for Sunday... any idea? heres a screen shot for the app and the classes i have that are displayed in my admin panel. https://imgur.com/a/YqZoxrn

Comment: @ZyzzShembesh I had to flatten the array of classes coming back from the filter. https://jsfiddle.net/fyt2rdnq/

Comment: Finally working! thanx for your help @ButchMonkey . please Update the answer so I can mark it as the right answer